To show nullity of $(A-2I)^2$ is 4 without calculating the product $(A-2I)\times (A-2I)$.
Let $$A=\begin{bmatrix}
2&0&2&6\\
0&2&0&0\\
0&0&2&0\\
0&0&0&2
\end{bmatrix}$$
Then as $A$ is upper triangular matrix so its spectrum is $\{2,2,2,2\}$.Now $A-2I=\begin{bmatrix}
0&0&2&6\\
0&0&0&0\\
0&0&0&0\\
0&0&0&0
\end{bmatrix}$Then clearly nulltiy of $A-2I$ is 3 and after some calculations one would get $(A-2I)^2=0$.I want to show it without matrix multiplication.I tried to prove it in this way:Since $N(A-2I)\subseteq N(A-2I)^2$,so nulliy of $(A-2I)^2\ge 3$$\implies \eta (A-2I)^2$ can be either $3$ or $4$.Now how should i proceed in order to prove that nullity of $A-2I$ is exactly $4$?(If someone can discuss it with the help of generalized eigenvector then it will be great help for me.)

Why don't you want to use that the square of such a matrix is obviously zero? It only has the nonzero entries $2$ and $6$ in the upper $2 \times 2$ corner. So we even do not need to multiply to see that the square is zero.

A slightly different approach: the image of $T-2I$ is the span of $(1,0,0,0)^T$, which is clearly in the nullspace of $T-2I$

@DietrichBurde can you explain it with the help of generalized eigen vector?

@NinadMunshi thank you.

@DietrichBurde I have just started to study the concepts of generalized eigenvector ,so i tried if i can relate it with generalized eigenvector.

Because the nullity is 3, the number of Jordan blocks is 3 and the largest is $2\times 2$. That means every generalized eigenvector is in the nullspace of $(A-2I)^2$.

@ArturoMagidin Thank you sir.

@ArturoMagidin This is what i wanted.

Its even easier than Jordan blocks; ${\sf range}(A-2I)={\sf span}((1,0,0,0))={\sf span}(e_1)$. Then ${\sf range}(A-2I)^2=(A-2I) e_1=0$ (in words, any vector in the range of $A-2I$ is a multiple of $e_1$ and this vector is in the null set of $A-2I$).

@TedBlack very nice explanation sir,this gives another dimension to solve the problem.Thank you so much.

Thanks. I just realised that @NinadMunshi provided exactly the same argument well before me!

So one way: let $E_{ij}$ be the matrix with a single $1$ in position $i,j$. Then we have the identity
$$
E_{ij}E_{kl} = \begin{cases}
0 & \text{if } j \neq k \\
E_{il} & \text{else}
\end{cases}.
$$
Your matrix is $2E_{13} + 6E_{14}$ and the square of this is zero because $k$ is always $1$ and $j$ is only ever $3$ or $4$.
By the way: if your matrix entries all have $i < j$ then when you square it, you'll have $i < j = k < l$ so $i$ and $l$ will be at least $2$ apart. Then in the cube, they're at least $3$ apart and so on. Eventually, when you take a large enough exponent, you'll get the zero matrix. These are called nilpotent matrices (nil meaning zero).

You gave another dimension to solve the problem.Thank you so much.
